# What would be an appropriate place for recommending links, websites, etc.?

Tags: feature-request, support, external-sources

What would be an appropriate place for recommending a link or website that could be of interest to a specific SE Q&A member site?

Such links often come up in answers, but as far as I could see, they are not listed collectively anywhere. In addition, once active in a community one often encounters links or web sites that could be of interest to the community and it would be nice to be able to share and tag them, in such a way that they could be searched together with the Q&A.

If this is the appropriate venue and if no such place exists, I would like therefore to suggest to extend the SE framework so that each member site can have a tab of **Links** next to the **Questions** tags where people could suggest and describe briefly to the community links (including web sites, books, podcasts etc.), and these links would be commented upon and voted up and down.

Comment: Tag-wikis seems like the appropriate place to post links. Whole-site seems too broad anyway, so per-tag links feel more reasonable

Comment: I've removed the [site recommendation] tag as this isn't looking for an SE site to place these links on, but rather a place for each site to place links that folks have recommended. I've also restored the [feature request] tag as the question is asking for such an ability if none exists.